# Is it more efficient to store MySQL results in an object during app start?

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I start my Node app, I store "static" MySQL data like game quests and game monsters which won't be modified in global objects. I'm not sure if is more efficient to do it this way or retrieving the data each time I need it. Sample code:

```
global.monsters;

doConn.query('SELECT * FROM monsters', function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('[MYSQL] Loaded monsters');
    monsters = results;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an important concept of code efficiency called [loop-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). It refers to anything that remains the same in every iteration of a loop.

Example:

```
for loop := range 1..100 {
  m = 42
  // other statements...
}
```

`m` is assigned a fixed value 100 times. Why do it 100 times? Why not assign it once, either before or after the loop, and save 99% of that work?

```
m = 42
for loop := range 1..100 {
  // other statements...
}
```

Some kinds of compilers can factor this code out during the compilation step. But maybe not Node.js. Even if it could factor it out, the code would be more clear to the reader if you write it with loop-invariant statements outside the loop. Otherwise the reader will waste some of their attention trying to figure out if there's some reason the statement is inside the loop.

The example of `m = 42` is very simple, but there could be more complex code that is still loop-invariant. Like querying data out of a database, the question you ask about.

There are exceptions to every rule. For example, some of the data about monsters could change frequently, even while players are playing, so your game might need to query repeatedly so it makes sure to have the latest data at all times.

But in general, if you can identify queries that are just as correct if you query them once at the start of the program, it's better to do that than to query them repeatedly.